# setTimeout function is out of sync

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just finishing up a simon says game written with javascript/jquery.  Everything is working okay, except for the playback sequence of simon after the second round. What happens is the new random button that simon presses decides to play as the second button in the playback sequence, when it should only be last (I say only because it does play at the end as well).  I figure there is a discrepancy between the setTimeout and setInterval, but I am clueless as to what it is. Any ideas as to why this is happening? Here is my codepen for good measure: http://codepen.io/vinnyA3/pen/avvGbM?editors=001
(Press on, then start to start the game)

```
function playSimonSequence() {
 var i = 0;
 var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
       //send in the correct button name and url to add the button pressed effect
       lightsAndSounds(buttonsAndUrls[simonArray[i]].button, buttonsAndUrls[simonArray[i]].url);
       ++i;
       if(i === simonArray.length){clearInterval(myInterval);}
 },1500);

//this is running at the wrong time
setTimeout(randomButtonPress, 2210);

}; //end simon sequence
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 1500ms interval timer and a 2210ms single timer running at the same time.  You should see the first interval at 1500ms, the single timer at 2210ms and then the second interval timer at 3000ms and so on.  That's how your code has it specified.

Both your timers are running at the same time.

Javascript does not wait to run your `setTimeout()` until all the intervals are done.  Instead, both timers are scheduled for their future time slot immediately and the run together.

If you want the `setTimeout()` to run after you clear the interval, then put the `setTimeout()` in the block of code where you call `clearInterval()`.

Comment: To add, you probably want the `setTimeout` to be alongside the `clearInterval` and possibly be set to `1500` too.

Comment: @elloM8 - I can't tell from your question exactly what order you want the timers to fire.  If you can explain that in your question, I can add a recommendation for how to achieve that.

Comment: @jfriend00  -Thank you! Can I ask why that was the case? You said that they are scheduled to run at the same time.  Does that mean they are set to run at the same time during the function's creation phase? (I'm trying to wrap my head around it).  And the interval is supposed to run first, then the timeout.

Comment: @Neit the Dark Absol  -Thanks !

Comment: `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` tell the system to schedule one or more timer events for the future.  They schedule that event and then the rest of your code keeps running.  `setInterval()` doesn't block and keep other code from running until you stop the interval.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oo, okay.  I got it now.  Thank you for your help!